# Documentation for include? method for active record ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where is the documentation for the include? method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

include? is actually a method in the Ruby array class.  It isn't a Rails method.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000265

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For records (I know it's 5+ years old), there is an `include?` method for ActiveRecord in Rails (at least now), which works for collections (e.g. has_many reference):
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L274

```
 def include?(record)
    if record.is_a?(reflection.klass)
      if record.new_record?
        include_in_memory?(record)
      else
        loaded? ? target.include?(record) : scope.exists?(record.id)
      end
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's from Ruby API, not Rails API:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001178